# Express/Node Res Variable Access With Javascript File

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I am using Express/Node and Pug to build an application.  I have a client side Javascript file that renders a JVectorMap based on data coming from an Express route and controllers.

I know how to access the data through the Pug view, and also if I use a script tag within the view.  My question is, how can I pull all of the javascript out to another file and still be able to access/work with the data being sent to the view?

Currently:
Route

```
router.get('/', dashboard.getRecentReviewsLimit, dashboard.getMapData,function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('dashboard', {
      user: req.user,
      dashreviews: res.locals.reviewlimit,
      mapdata: res.locals.mapdata
    });
});
```

Pug Template/View (this script updates a div with the map):

```
script(type='text/javascript').

    var mapData = !{JSON.stringify(mapdata)};

    var max = 0,
    min = Number.MAX_VALUE,
    cc,
    ........
```

How can I pull all of the script code to a separate file and still gain access to the `!{JSON.stringify(mapdata)}` data?

Comment: You could use two scripts. The first is mostly generated by Pug. It would be something like `window.DATA = !{JSON.stringify(mapdata)}`. The other script just access the global `window.DATA` object.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest thing to do is to just generate your javascript via pug as well.

Given something like `./views/js/datamapper.pug`:

```
var mapData = !{JSON.stringify(mapdata)};

var max = 0,
min = Number.MAX_VALUE,
cc,
........
```

You could then have a route like:

```
router.get('/datamap.js', (req, res) => {
  res.render('js/datamapper', { mapdata: ... });
});
```